# Display formula in cell vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'd like to make the cell to appear  as follows()

Desired outcome-- as I hover over cell
`'E15'=(1+9.27%)*(1+C15)-1"` and as I hover away the equation is evaluated

What I don't want  E15 = (0.0000007)-1

I have two formulas that I was working on but I just can't seem to get it right.
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
Range("E15").Formula = "=(" & 1 + "(" & Range("D15").Value & )"") * (" & 1 + "(" & Range("C15") & "))" - 1"
Range("E15").Formula = "=(" & 1 + "(" & Range("D15").Value & ")" & ") * (" & 1 + "(" & Range("C15") & ") & ") - 1"
```

Comment: What if you remove the "=" here : "=(", and let it "("?

Comment: That is just the formula,  How have your tried the hover over?

Comment: BTW: `"=(1 + " & Range("D15").Value & ") * (1 + " & Range("C15").Address(0,0) & ") - 1"`

Comment: or, since Range("C15").Address is C15:  `Range("E15").Formula = "=( 1 + " & Range("D15").Value & ") * ( 1 + C15) - 1"`

Comment: Scorceri and  scott craner. Both solutions worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Range("E15")
        .ClearComments
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Visible = False
        .Comment.Text Text:=Chr(39) & .Address(0, 0) & Chr(39) & "  " & .Formula
    End With
End Sub
```

produces:

[image]

NOTE:

It is equally easy to place the Comment in an adjacent cell.